# How to kill pattern processes in linux

Tags: linux

In `linux`, there are a series of processes whose names contain `aaa`, please use one command to kill all processes whose names contain `aaa`, but there is a process whose name is `aaab`, and you cannot kill the process.

Answer (score 1):

From the `killall` man page, we can see that the `-r` option matches for any regex:

> -r, --regexp
>
> Interpret process name pattern as a POSIX extended regular expression

Or you can also use `pkill -f`.

In your case, since you don't want to match against `aaab` processes, you can use something like this

```
killall -r "(?!.*aaab.*).*aaa.*"
```

Where `?!` is a negative lookahead and will not match anything that contains `aaab`.

I would suggest you do a dry-run to make sure it will grep for the right thing before killing and processes